# Pandas: why can you do arithmetic on series with non-identical indexes, but not comparisons?

Tags: python, pandas

In Pandas, operations on Series are done with respect to the index. For example:

```py
import pandas as pd

foo = pd.Series(data=[1, 2, 3, 4, 5], index=[0, 1, 2, 3, 4])
bar = pd.Series(data=[2, 3, 6, 5, -3], index=[1, 2, 3, 4, 5])
```

These two Series have indexes that partially overlap. When I add them, the values in the overlapping parts of the indexes are added, and the parts that don't overlap get `NaN`:

```py
foo + bar
```

```
0     NaN
1     4.0
2     6.0
3    10.0
4    10.0
5     NaN
dtype: float64
```

```py
foo - bar
```

```
0    NaN
1    0.0
2    0.0
3   -2.0
4    0.0
5    NaN
dtype: float64
```

However, the same logic does not seem to apply when using comparison operators, like `==`, `!=`, `<`, `<=`, `>`, and `>=`. For example:

```py
foo >= bar
```

```
ValueError: Can only compare identically-labeled Series objects
```

I would have expected this to match on the indices in the same way, giving something like

```
0    NA
1    True
2    True
3    False
4    True
5    NA
dtype: bool
```

Why doesn't this happen? And is there a way to workaround this limitation and get the above result in a straightforward way?

Comment: `foo.ge(bar)` ? `bool`type `pd.Series` can't contain `na` values. I don't know why it is not working with operators.

Comment: There are nullable boolean series now: `pd.Series([pd.NA, True, False], dtype="boolean")`.

Comment: How do you want to use them in this case? `bool` type is returned, not `boolean`

Comment: When the index is present in both series, do the comparison as normal, giving `True` or `False`. When the index is in one but not the other, give `NA`. I don't mind whether it's `bool` or `boolean`.

Comment: https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/1134  This was a choice by the pandas gods.    I got that problems/ambiguity happens if indexes are not unique.   With mathemical operations, you get a Cartesian result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

not sure why it is not possible nor what you're trying to accomplish specifically. But this is an idea:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd


foo = pd.Series(data=[1, 2, 3, 4, 5], index=[0, 1, 2, 3, 4])
bar = pd.Series(data=[2, 3, 6, 5, -3], index=[1, 2, 3, 4, 5])

ratio = (foo+bar)/bar
foo_greater = ratio.apply(lambda x: x if np.isnan(x) else True if x>=2 else False)

print(foo_greater) 

Returns:

0      NaN
1     True
2     True
3    False
4     True
5      NaN
dtype: object
```

Leveraging the fact you can execute addition and division, if the value in "ratio" is not NaN and greater or equal to 2, then foo >= bar, hence True.

Similar logic can be applied for all the other comparison operations.